# Getting INVALID_REQUEST from Google Maps API for valid addresses

Tags: php, google-maps, query-string

I'm doing some tests with Google Maps API and for some reason there is valid addresses that return status INVALID_REQUEST for no apparent reason. Here is my php code

```
    $request_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".urlencode($address);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
    $status = $xml->status;
    return $status;
```

$address example:

```
    $address = "R. Espírito Santo, Viana, ES, Brasil" // status INVALID_REQUEST
```

but if I try to access the URL directly it return status OK

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=R.%20Espírito%20Santo,%20Viana,%20ES,%20Brasil](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=R.%20Esp%C3%ADrito%20Santo,%20Viana,%20ES,%20Brasil)

For some addresses it returns OK, but for others INVALID_REQUEST using exactly the same code changing only the address. Accessing the URL directly always returns OK.

Any clues?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was an character encoding problem. utf8_encode() ([info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)) solved it.

```
    $address = utf8_encode($address);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `urlencode()` ([info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php))

```
$address     = "R. Espírito Santo, Viana, ES, Brasil" // this can't be passed as query string
$request_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".urlencode($address); // urlencode() solves this
$xml         = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
$status      = $xml->status;
return $status;
```